# bootstrap-tagsinput do not worked

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

I can  see  a good control

http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/

But based on it i tried codes below it didn't work ,
Can any one help me

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js" ></script>

<script src="http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/bower_components/google-code-prettify-lite/prettify.js"></script>
<script src="http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/bootstrap-2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/dist/bootstrap-tagsinput.js"></script>
<script src="http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/dist/bootstrap-tagsinput-angular.js"></script>

<body>
<br />
<input type="text" value="" data-role="tagsinput"  />
<br />
</body>
<script>
$('input').tagsinput({
  typeahead: {
    source: [{"value":1,"text":"Amsterdam"},
{"value":4,"text":"Washington"},
{"value":7,"text":"Sydney"},
{"value":10,"text":"Beijing"},
{"value":13,"text":"Cairo"}]
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Fix the path to bootstrap.min.js

Comment: That is not the problem

Comment: I am getting TypeError: tagsinput[arg1] is not a function

Comment: It is not recognized as a function because the .js is not included correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of a know bug :
https://github.com/TimSchlechter/bootstrap-tagsinput/issues/42

To resolve, do not use data-role="tagsinput" and $('input').tagsinput(...) together.

[Tagsinput is not a function, using bootstrap 3 and tags-input plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20125061/tagsinput-is-not-a-function-using-bootstrap-3-and-tags-input-plugin#)

Answer (score 0):

I use the same plug-in in a project
the problem with the typeahead source it need to be a json with simple elements no objects

Take a look at this fiddle, Im sure It will help you

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Palapas/WtC27/1/)

```
$('input').tagsinput({
    typeahead: {
        source: function (query, process) {
            cities = [];
            map = {};

            var data = [{
                "value": 1,
                    "text": "Amsterdam"
            }, {
                "value": 4,
                    "text": "Washington"
            }, {
                "value": 7,
                    "text": "Sydney"
            }, {
                "value": 10,
                    "text": "Beijing"
            }, {
                "value": 13,
                    "text": "Cairo"
            }];

            $.each(data, function (i, city) {
                map[city.text] = city;
                cities.push(city.text);
            });

            return (cities);
        }
    }
});
```

---

PreFetched Json

```
cities = [];
map = {};

var preFetchResult = function (query, callback) {
    $.get("/cities", {
        "data": query
    }, function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (i, city) {
            map[city.text] = city;
            cities.push(city.text);
        });
    });
};

preFetchResult.done(function (response) {
    $('input').tagsinput({
        typeahead: {
            source: function (query, process) {
                return (cities);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: How can I use prefetch JSON data with your example?

Comment: Check the updated answer, use the get as a promise, let me know if it work for you =)