# Tagsinput is not a function, using bootstrap 3 and tags-input plugin

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-tags-input

I'm using bootstrap 3 with jquery 1.10 and I'm tring to using tags-input plugin (http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/bootstrap3/) but it doesn't works.
This is my error:

```
TypeError: tagsinput[arg1] is not a function
var retVal = tagsinput[arg1](arg2);
```

This is my html code:

```
    <head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAv92iA1TcfCnk4-bDg7BAJoKOCnh1g7oQ&sensor=false"></script>

<link href="/qtip2/css/jquery.qtip.min.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
<link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
<link href="/css/1309_ciceroos_b2b.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
<link href="/css/1310_longdistance.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
<link href="/bootstrap3.0.0/assets/css/bootstrap-tagsinput.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" ><script type="text/javascript" src="/bootstrap3.0.0/assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/infobox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/qtip2/js/jquery.qtip.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/qtip2/js/imagesloaded.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/bootstrap3.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/bootstrap3.0.0/assets/js/holder.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/bootstrap3.0.0/assets/js/bootstrap-tagsinput.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
                    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
                        //$('.bootstrap-tagsinput input').attr("value", "interessi");   
                        $('#idInputWhat').tagsinput('add', 'mare');
                        $('#idInputWhat').tagsinput('add', 'vino'); 

                        $('#idInputWhat').tagsinput({
                            maxTags: 3
                            });                         
                    });
                </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form class="form-inline" role="form" id="idFormSearch" method="GET" action="javascript:void(0);">
                                 <div class="form-group col-md-offset-1 col-md-5 _interestInput">
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Quali sono le tue passioni?" data-role="tagsinput" class="form-control input-lg" name="what" id='idInputWhat' value=""/> 
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-3 _interestInput">
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="dove"  class="form-control input-lg" name="where" id='idInputWhere' />
                                    <input type="hidden" name="start" id='idStart' value="0"/> 
                                </div>
                                 <div class="col-md-3 _searchButton">
                                    <input class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit" value="Ispirami!"></input>
                                  </div>
                              </form>
        </body>
```

Please, Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you specify what tags-input plugin are you trying to use?

Comment: yes sorry, it is: http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/bootstrap3/

Comment: How are jQuery and the plugin JS files being included? Is there more to the HEAD that what's shown? The plugin works fine: http://bootply.com/92587

Comment: I'm editing the question and i have add all the code in the head.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It looks like if you specify both `data-role="tagsinput"` and use `$('#idInputWhat').tagsinput('add', 'vino');` then it gives that error. Try removing the `data-role` attribute, and use only the explicit `.tagsinput()`.

I'd consider this a bug in the tagsinput plugin.

Seems to be confirmed here; https://github.com/TimSchlechter/bootstrap-tagsinput/issues/42

Comment: I was facing the similar problem, but by adding the line '$('#idInputWhat').tagsinput('add', 'vino'); ', I'm able to add the tag even with 'data-role=tagsinput' written

Answer (score 1):

Check if you included bootstrap-tagsinput.js script.

It seems working for me: [JSBin link](http://jsbin.com/uVAtOTIp/1/edit)

Comment: Yes, I include the library, but in your code if you insert this: $('#idInputWhat').tagsinput({
    maxTags: 3
    });
it doesn't works