# tags-input plugin not work with bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I work with [Tags-input](http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/bootstrap3/) bootstrap plugin. this worked with typehead and Json Files But in bootstrap 3 this plugin not work for me.

HTML:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" />
```

JS:

```
$('input').tagsinput({
    typeahead: {
        source: function (query) {
            return $.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TimSchlechter/bootstrap-tagsinput/master/examples/assets/citynames.json');
        }
    }
});
```

What's Problem? how do can i fix this ?

[DEMO JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/YTUt2/)

Comment: Look in your error console. Looking at your fiddle in Chrome, I'm getting `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` for both `bootstrap-tagsinput.js` and `typeahead.min.js`, and then an error calling `$('input').tagsinput()` (because it's undefined). Firefox seems to load the scripts, but then fails somewhere else with `Error: one of local, prefetch, or remote is required`.

Comment: It's possible this isn't working because https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ is returning the scripts with a MIME type of text/plain. The browsers probably won't think that's a JS file.

Comment: @OllyHodgson: this just simple! i check in my localhost this not work for me!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this one it is easy to use it is jquery's tags input. 
here is its [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7aDak/).
**html:**

```
<p>This is a basic tag input: 
    <input id="tag1" value="alpha,beta,gamma" />
</p>
```

**JS:**

```
$('#tag1').tagsInput({
    // my parameters here
});
```

and if you still want to use bootstrap tags input then check this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20125061/tagsinput-is-not-a-function-using-bootstrap-3-and-tags-input-plugin#)

Answer (score 0):

As the [typeahead.js plugin](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/) has evolved the [tagsinput pluging](https://github.com/timschlechter/bootstrap-tagsinput) support for typeahead is outdated and does not work with the latest version. One solution is to implement typeahead.js out side of the tagsinput plugin and leveraging the tagsinput plugin strictly for the tagging part. Here goes a sample implementation.

Assuming your Json object looked like this:

```
var a = [
    {
        'Key': '1',
        'Value': 'Alabama'
    },
    {
        'Key': '2',
        'Value': 'California'
    },
    {
        'Key': '3',
        'Value': 'New York'
    }];
```

Then you could have a method like this to setup the plugin:

```
function addTypeAhead(elem) {
    var elt = $(elem);

    elt.tagsinput({
        itemValue: 'Key',
        itemText: 'Value',
        freeInput: false
    });

    elt.tagsinput('input').typeahead(null, {
        displayKey: 'Value',
        source: function(query, process) {
            // do your Ajax call here
            return $.get({
                url: yourUrl,
                data: { Query: query }
            }).done(function(msg) {
                process(msg.Data);
            }).fail(function(jqXhr, textStatus) {
                alert("Request failed: " + textStatus);
            });
        }
    }).bind('typeahead:selected', $.proxy(function (obj, selectedItem) {
        // add tag to tagsinput plugin
        this.tagsinput('add', selectedItem);
        // reset input of tagsinput plugin
        this.tagsinput('input').typeahead('val', '');
        // handle when user selects tag here
    }, elt));

    elt.on('itemRemoved', function (event) {
        // handle when user removes tag here
    });
}
```