# $(...).tagsinput is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tags-input

I must be missing something simple but I can't see it. I am using the Bootstrap tagsinput plugin and I am trying to follow some of the examples here:
http://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/

Here is my code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.tagsinput/0.4.2/bootstrap-tagsinput.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.tagsinput/0.4.2/bootstrap-tagsinput.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="cities" class="form-control" value="New York,London" data-role="tagsinput" type="text">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function() {
        $('#cities').tagsinput({
          maxTags: 3
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am getting the following Javascript error:

```
tagsinput.html:15 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tagsinput is not a function
```

I tried removing `data-role="tagsinput"` as suggested in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20125061/tagsinput-is-not-a-function-using-bootstrap-3-and-tags-input-plugin) but the input becomes a regular textbox and the exception still occurs.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried reordering your script tags so that jQuery and Bootstrap come before the tagsinput plugin?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you're loading 2 jquery min files in your `script` tags.

remove the one after `bootstrap-tagsinput.min.js` or since the 2nd one is newer version load that instead of the 1st one.

http://jsbin.com/xarasebibi/edit?html,output

Answer (score 0):

You duplicated jquery links. one at the top and the other at the bottom. and the bootstrap-tag-min script has to be linked only after you have included jquery link. see below for more info. Hope that helps

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.tagsinput/0.4.2/bootstrap-tagsinput.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="cities" class="form-control" value="New York,London" data-role="tagsinput" type="text">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.tagsinput/0.4.2/bootstrap-tagsinput.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function() {
        $('#cities').tagsinput({
          maxTags: 3
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```